# How do I add a level gauge for 100 lb propane tank?

Tags: plumbing, gas, propane

I just got this [100lb propane tank](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Worthington-Pro-Grade-100-lb-Empty-Propane-Tank/1080473), and I also got [this two stage regulator](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Char-Broil-Dual-Stage-Propane-Tank-Regulator/999919552). I want to add a gauge so I can check the tank level, I only find gauges that convert POL LP Tank Valve to QCC1 and that's not what I want. I found this [gauge with regulators](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08889TX92) on Amazon, but it has terrible reviews.

Does anyone know a good solution? Please link if possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Put it on a scale.

The only thing that a pressure gauge tells you about a propane tank is its temperature, or that it's completely empty. The tank should have a "tare weight" marked on it (the empty weight) and if it weighs 100 lbs more than that, it's full.

Propane is transported as a liquified gas under pressure. So long as there is **any** liquid in the tank, pressure indicates tank temperature.

Weight will tell you how much has been used.

The traditional solution is TWO tanks, an indicator, and a valve that switches which tank is "primary" (and raises the indicator when it becomes empty) and which tank is "reserve" (which the valve draws from when the primary is empty.) You remove and refill the empty tank, and switch the valve (which causes the indicator to lower) to make the other tank "primary" until it's empty and you repeat.

Much larger fixed tanks typically have an internal float gauge to sense the liquid level, which is not *terribly* accurate, but generally good enough to tell you to call the truck and get it filled up before you run out. I've never seen one for small tanks.

Comment: I agree about accuracy, but an inline tank gauge is a lot less hassle than trying to find a scale for a 100# tank that is reasonably priced. What I do is firmly grasp the tank and move it back and forth to see how low it might be. By doing that, I can tell the liquid level. It's not accurate either, but it's a good way to determine the fluid level when you have no other means.

Comment: A simple, mechanical bathroom scale should be more than sufficient and will generally handle up to 300 pounds, @gwally. Generally speaking, those aren't too expensive - I just found one online for $26 that supports up to 400 pounds.

Comment: @FreeMan, I use all of my 100# tanks outside. To leave a scale under a tank, adjusted for tare seems like a great idea, but they're not weatherproof. Once you find one that's weatherproof, the cost goes up significantly. To use a scale to weigh a tank, you need to firmly grasp the tank and move it back and forth to get it on the scale, then you're basically where you were with my suggestion.

Comment: If you just need to check every so often, rather than leave a gauge/scale on it constantly, the hanging kind of scale works well.  I use a luggage scale for weighing my BBQ propane tanks, but something like this would work for 100lb ones: https://www.webstaurantstore.com/avaweigh-hsd330-330-lb-digital-hanging-scale-fish-scale-industrial-scale-produce-scale/334HSD330.html

Comment: Thank you all! Saved me from buying something I wont need, I'll keep the 100lb tank and will have a small bbq one as a spare, just in case

Answer (score 1):

Get an infrared temperature "gun". The liquid in the tank is colder than the pressurised gas above it. It doesn't need to be a particularly accurate one; you're just finding the liquid level

Answer (score 1):

I would do this the same way that HVAC technicians check the refrigerant level in receiver tanks (rooftop condensing units).

Easiest way is if you have any sort of IR measuring device.

Run hot water down the side of the tank.  Barring that, use a heat gun or hair dryer on LOW and heat a strip of area from tank top to bottom.  Be careful to not overheat the tank.  Only needs a few degrees above ambient temperature.

Now look for the level where the area in the tank above the liquid level is warmer than the liquid level below.  Your IR gun will show this easily.

You used to be able to purchase a temperature indicating strip that sticks to the side of the tank.  Not sure if those are available anymore.